# Apply method to all elements in enumerable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

I have a list, trying to accomplish the following. I want to run a mapper method for each item in the list...can't seem to get the syntax correct

```
var viewModelList = result.MyEnumerable.Select(MyMapper(item goes here))

 public static MyViewModel MyMapper(Item item)
        {
            var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
            //do some stuff
            return viewModel;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use:

```
result.MyEnumerable.Select(r => MyMapper(r));
```

or use a method group:

```
result.MyEnumerable.Select(MyMapper);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result.MyEnumerable.Select(x => MyMapper(x));
```

or more condensed

```
result.MyEnumerable.Select(x => new MyViewModel
{
    // use x in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var viewModelList = result.MyEnumerable.Select(s=> MyMapper(s))

 public static MyViewModel MyMapper(Item item)
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        //do some stuff
        return viewModel;
    }
```